I'm looking for a French movie about a man who kills all the members of a jury, in a single day
I saw this film so long ago I couldn't tell you if there were subtitles or not.
There might have not even been any dialog.
A man leaves his house and his wife kisses him goodbye.
He starts killing people.
The police are trying to work out what's going on. All these people being killed in one day.
The police now realise, all the victims were on a jury where a young man was sentenced to death.
The man doing the killing is the young man's father.
The last part of the movie is a race between the police and the father to get to the last jury members.
Of course, there is a plot twist at the end.

Saw this on TV in 1986, and have been wanting to know the title for ages (but never got around to asking). Thanks for asking.

Possibly A Full Day's Work (1973)  (French: Une journée bien remplie)
Wikipedia

The story concerns a baker who has carefully planned the execution of the nine jurors who sent his son to the gallows for murder. Before the police or anyone else can stop him, he calmly does away with each of the nine in a grim but methodical way.





Yes, that's the one.
In the trailer, it opens with the French policemen on top of a building looking in alternate directions. I remember that scene distinctly.

This is a comedy!?

@Kyralessa Other French movies also blend noir with comedy. It's a thing. A famous example is "Alphaville" (1965), written and directed by Jean-Luc Godard, which has noir and science fiction elements with occasional weird comedy.

@Kyralessa "Tragedy is when I cut my finger. Comedy is when you fall into an open sewer and die." - Mel Brooks

Plenty of comedies involve deaths outside of French movies. In "Kind Hearts and Coronets" (1949) all the members of a noble family are gruesomely murdered.
